# Can´t find a hash in the downloaded Version of Haveibeenpwned, even though it is in there (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I´m trying to build a local version of the Haveibeenpwned password database.
So I downloaded the File from the [website](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords) (NTLM Hashes, ordered by hash), unzipped it and wrote a simple python programm as proof of concept:

```
input_file = open("Path/to/my/file","r")#HIBP Textfile (20GB)

test = "32ED87BDB5FDC5E9CBA88547376818D4" #123456
test2 = "8846F7EAEE8FB117AD06BDD830B7586C" #password
  
for lines in input_file: 
    line = input_file.readline()
    line = line.split(":")
    hash_value = line[0]
    if(hash_value == test):
        print("Pwned!")
        print(line)
    elif(hash_value == test2):
        print("Pwned")
        print(line)
    else:
        pass
```

This works for the "password" hash but not for "123456". Output of the script:

```
 Pwned
['8846F7EAEE8FB117AD06BDD830B7586C', '3861493\n']
>>>
```

I opened the file with EmEditor and searched for the 123456 hash and it is in there. But I´m not sure why the script does not find it. I suppose it has something to do with the file size of around 20GB, but I´m not sure how to mitigate this.

I know this is by no means efficient, it´s only purpose is to check if everything works.

**Edit:** corrected a little mistake: I did not download the "ordered by prevalence" version of HIBP but the "ordered by hash" version

Comment: I´m trying to build a database to check localy if a password has already been breached. Can´t see whats wrong with that?

Comment: @S3DEV - this is not a security problem. What the OP is doing is above board - various folks in the security community do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is skipping every second line, because `for lines in input_file:` goes to the next line as well as `line = input_file.readline()`

try it this way:

```
for line in input_file: 
    line = line.split(":")
    ...
```

Comment: @OperaofthePhantom - upvotes are always more welcome than writing "thanks" in the comment :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop, I tried upvoting but I did not have the reputation yet, but I´ll get back to that as soon as I have the 15 points